# Why is cmake-gui not setting environment variables like it should?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm trying to compile M2aia (look it up on GitHub), which is based on MITK and I get the cmake-error:

```
[  1%] Performing update step for 'MITK-Data'
[  1%] No patch step for 'MITK-Data'
[  1%] No configure step for 'MITK-Data'
[  2%] No build step for 'MITK-Data'
[  2%] No install step for 'MITK-Data'
[  2%] Completed 'MITK-Data'
[  4%] Built target MITK-Data
[  4%] Performing update step for 'M2aia-Data'
[  5%] No patch step for 'M2aia-Data'
[  5%] No configure step for 'M2aia-Data'
[  6%] No build step for 'M2aia-Data'
[  6%] No install step for 'M2aia-Data'
[  6%] Completed 'M2aia-Data'
[  8%] Built target M2aia-Data
[ 13%] Built target Poco
[ 18%] Built target DCMTK
[ 23%] Built target tinyxml2
[ 28%] Built target GDCM
[ 32%] Built target Eigen
[ 36%] Built target ANN
[ 40%] Built target CppUnit
[ 44%] Built target HDF5
[ 49%] Built target ITK
[ 54%] Built target VTK
[ 60%] Built target Boost
[ 60%] Performing update step for 'lz4'
[ 61%] No patch step for 'lz4'
[ 61%] Performing configure step for 'lz4'
loading initial cache file /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/tmp/lz4-cache-Debug.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/src/lz4-build
[ 62%] Performing build step for 'lz4'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target lz4_shared
[100%] Built target lz4_shared
[ 62%] Performing install step for 'lz4'
[100%] Built target lz4_shared
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/lib/liblz4d.so.1.9.3
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/lib/liblz4d.so.1
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/lib/liblz4d.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/include/lz4.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/include/lz4frame.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/include/lz4hc.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/share/man/man1/lz4.1
-- Up-to-date: /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/lib/pkgconfig/liblz4.pc
[ 62%] Completed 'lz4'
[ 64%] Built target lz4
[ 69%] Built target CTK
[ 73%] Built target DCMQI
[ 78%] Built target MatchPoint
[ 82%] Built target Qwt
[ 86%] Built target OpenSlide
[ 91%] Built target ElastixBinaries
[ 92%] No configure step for 'MITK-Utilities'
[ 92%] No build step for 'MITK-Utilities'
[ 93%] No install step for 'MITK-Utilities'
[ 94%] Completed 'MITK-Utilities'
[ 95%] Built target MITK-Utilities
[ 96%] Performing configure step for 'MITK-Configure'
loading initial cache file /home/maia/Documents/m2aia/build/ep/tmp/MITK-Configure-cache-Debug.cmake
-- Performing Test HAS_FLAG_-std=c17
-- Performing Test HAS_FLAG_-std=c17 - Success
-- ------- Using build configuration "M2aiaRelease" -------
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=gnu
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=gnu - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=gnu
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=gnu - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=unknown_pragmas
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=unknown_pragmas - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=unknown_pragmas
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=unknown_pragmas - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=strict_overflow
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=strict_overflow - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=strict_overflow
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=strict_overflow - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=nonnull
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=nonnull - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=nonnull
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=nonnull - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=stringop_overread
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX_FLAG__Wno_error=stringop_overread - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=stringop_overread
-- Performing Test HAS_C_FLAG__Wno_error=stringop_overread - Failed
-- Trying to find DCMTK expecting DCMTKConfig.cmake
-- Trying to find DCMTK expecting DCMTKConfig.cmake - ok
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/maia/Documents/m2aia/MITK/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/maia/Documents/m2aia/MITK/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:37 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:37 (cmake_minimum_required):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0091 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:27 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0091 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:996 (message):
  BLUEBERRY_USE_QT_HELP is required to be set to ON


make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MITK-Configure.dir/build.make:94: ep/src/MITK-Configure-stamp/MITK-Configure-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1448: CMakeFiles/MITK-Configure.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

However the variable is set in the cmake-gui (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot of cmake-gui]

I did try deleting the cache and set it anew but it changed nothing in the end.
I also tried with different data types: With bool I set the checkbox to be set, which caused the same error. I even tried the string "1" but to no avail.
I honestly don't know what is wrong here and why it doesn't work.

I am using cmake version 3.24.1.

Any suggestions are appreciated. :)

Edit: attached the whole output of `make` command

Comment: According to the [code](https://github.com/RabadanLab/MITKats/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L966), before the error message it should be a message explaining why `BLUEBERRY_USE_QT_HELP` is treated to be OFF (even if you set it to ON).

Comment: Please post all CMake messages.

Comment: @KamilCuk added the entire output